# Loading owl file with Jena

Tags: java, jena, owl, ontology

I load several OWL files (RDF/XML serialization) with Jena as `OntModel`. 
For some files I get an error when reading them with `ontoModel.read()`:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpMessage`.

I have `org.apache.httpcore-sources.jar` in the classpath.

The file which currently poses problem is: [ontologydesignpatterns.org/cp/owl/timeindexedpersonrole.owl](http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/cp/owl/timeindexedpersonrole.owl)

I saved it with Protege as RDF/XML, trying with both extensions `.owl` and `.rdf`.

The code:

```
public static OntModel getOntologyModel(String ontoFile)
{   
    OntModel ontoModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM, null);
    try 
    {
        InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(ontoFile);
        try 
        {
            ontoModel.read(in, null);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        LOGGER.info("Ontology " + ontoFile + " loaded.");
    } 
    catch (JenaException je) 
    {
        System.err.println("ERROR" + je.getMessage());
        je.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return ontoModel;
}
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: please insert project structure, lib folder

Comment: I am able to load your file with your code. Make sure that you are passing owl file with correct name. Code is correct.

Comment: Thanks. I triple-checked, the file name is correct and the file exists. The error is actually coming from `org.apache.jena.riot.system.stream.LocatorHTTP.performOpen(LocatorHTTP.java:41)`. I also tried to put the base name as arg of the read method, but same error for the same file. Might be a stupid error somewhere, but I do not manage to spot it.

Comment: The file linked has imports to other ontologies - one of them might be the problem. I'd try loading each one to see if anything useful emerges.

Comment: Thanks, you're right that might the imports. There is actually a chain of imports; other files pose problem as well, which make the whole stuff quite cumbersome. I think I will just hard-code the few classes of my initial file...

Comment: `ontoModel.read(ontoFile);` will work (unless quite old Jena) if the file name has an extension.

Comment: Reading the file directly does not work (for this file only) and hit the same error. Someone else got a similar pb when reading owl file with imports, but no solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850654/how-to-read-ontology-file-with-owlimports-in-jena. Thanks to all for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the binary download, put all the jars in the lib/ directory on the classpath.  org.apache.httpcore-sources.jar isn't the right jar.. You seem to be missing at least httpclient-4.2.6.jar and httpcore-4.2.5.jar.

If you use maven, use the artifact:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
 <artifactId>apache-jena-libs</artifactId>
 <type>pom</type>
 <version>X.Y.Z</version>
</dependency>
```

to get the same set, but managed by maven, or whatever builer you are using.

Comment: Hello, thanks, that was it! Simply missing the good libraries to handle the imports. Now it works :)